# Javascript program to find combination of length 2 for two arrays of different lengths

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have two array `['b','c','d','e']` & `['h','i','k','l','m','n']`
I want to find combinations of length 2 for array above using Javascript/AngularJS program.
e.g.

```
['bh','bi','bk','bk','bl','bm','bn','ch,'ci','ck' ...]
```

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I think the function map is unnecessary because the function reduce can do that.

Comment: hi, what would be the values of acc, v, i... i tried using above code in my JS file but see errors

Answer (score 0):

Here is *functional programming* ES6 solution:

```js
var array = ['b','c','d','e'];
var array2 =  ['h','i','k','l','m','n'];

var result = array.reduce( (a, v) =>
    [...a, ...array2.map(x=>v+x)],
[]);
console.log(result);

/*---------OR--------------*/

var result1 = array.reduce( (a, v, i) =>
    a.concat(array2.map( w => v + w )),
[]);
console.log(result1);

/*-------------OR(without arrow function)---------------*/

var result2 = array.reduce(function(a, v, i) {
    a = a.concat(array2.map(function(w){
      return v + w
    }));
    return a;
    },[]
);
console.log(result2);

/*----------for single array------------*/

var result4 = array.reduce( (a, v, i) =>
    [...a, ...array.slice(i+1).map(x=>v+'-'+x)],
[]);
console.log(result4);
```

Comment: Thanks, but what would be values of a , v and i.

Comment: @neha try second one

Comment: I am getting errors when i used your code in my JS file..do i need to import any files for funnctional programming? I am new to jS. any help apprecriated. I see red marks under "=>" sign

Comment: @neha you are using an older browser that doesn't support an _arrow notation_. `w => v + w` is the same as `function(w){return v + w}`

Comment: @neha _what would be values of a , v and i._ read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Thank you. How can i achieve the same for one single array . e.g I have one array  ['b','c','d','e'] , but i want result to be ['b-c','b-d','b-e','c-d'..]; I want to add a hyphen between items. thanks

Comment: Thanks[
  "b-b",
  "b-c",
  "b-d",
  "b-e",
  "c-b",
  "c-c",
  "c-d",
  "c-e",
  "d-b",
  "d-c",
  "d-d",
  "d-e",
  "e-b",
  "e-c",
  "e-d",
  "e-e"
] but this has 'b-b','c-c','d-d','e-e' , how can i get rid of those?

Comment: @neha sorry for wrong output, just add `slice` (see in code,updated it)

Comment: Why to make so complex:  function combinations(a1, a2) { 
  var result = [];
  a1.forEach(function(v1, id1){ 
    a2.forEach(function(v2, id2){ 
      result.push(v1+v2)
    })
  })
  
  return result;
  
}

Answer (score 0):

Use nesting [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) calls and combine the letters. Flatten the arrays by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const arr1 = ['b','c','d','e'];
const arr2 = ['h','i','k','l','m','n'];

const result = [].concat(...arr1.map((l1) => arr2.map((l2) => l1 + l2)));

console.log(result);
```